# Why doesn't my script work on FreeBSD, even though it seems to work on Linux? It's as if FreeBSD ignores "if"

Tags: bash, sh, freebsd

I am trying to write a portable installation script for building the compiler for my programming language. You can see the script [here](https://flatassembler.github.io/AEC_specification.html#AEC_to_x86):

```bash
mkdir ArithmeticExpressionCompiler
cd ArithmeticExpressionCompiler
if command -v wget &> /dev/null
then
  wget https://flatassembler.github.io/Duktape.zip
else
  curl -o Duktape.zip https://flatassembler.github.io/Duktape.zip
fi
unzip Duktape.zip
if command -v gcc &> /dev/null
then
  gcc -o aec aec.c duktape.c -lm # The linker that comes with recent versions of Debian Linux insists that "-lm" is put AFTER the source files, or else it outputs some confusing error message.
else
  clang -o aec aec.c duktape.c -lm
fi
./aec analogClock.aec
if command -v gcc &> /dev/null
then
  gcc -o analogClock analogClock.s -m32
else
  clang -o analogClock analogClock.s -m32
fi
./analogClock
```

However, when I run it on FreeBSD, it complains that `wget` is not found. But the script checks whether `wget` exists before calling it. `wget` is not supposed to be called on FreeBSD. Now, I know FreeBSD uses `sh` rather than `bash`, and I suppose my script is not actually POSIX-compliant. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well you could Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. That said `&>` is `bashism`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02) Spec:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator  ( '&'
> ), the shell shall execute the command asynchronously in a subshell.
> This means that the shell shall not wait for the command to finish
> before executing the next command.

In posix `&>` is not supported by posix instead it will see `&` as a background command indicator causing your command to be run asynchronously with the next part `> /dev/null` which is seen as a seperate command. This is basically if you were to run:

```
command -v wget & > /dev/null
```

Instead you have to redirect another way:

```
command -v wget >/dev/null 2>&1
```