# How to check whether GCC exists, execute it if it exists, and otherwise try executing CLANG, in a BASH script?

Tags: bash

[Here](https://flatassembler.github.io/AEC_specification#AEC_to_WebAssembly) is how I tried it:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly.git
cd AECforWebAssembly
if command -v g++ &> /dev/null
then
  g++ -std=c++11 -o aec AECforWebAssembly.cpp
else
  clang++ -o aec AECforWebAssembly.cpp
fi
cd analogClock
../aec analogClock.aec
npx -p wabt wat2wasm analogClock.wat
node analogClock
```

However, I get the following message when I try that on WSL Ubuntu:

```
teo@DESKTOP-C29Q2SM:~/AECforWebAssembly$ if command -v g++ &> /dev/null
> then
>   g++ -std=c++11 -o aec AECforWebAssembly.cpp
> else
>   clang++ -o aec AECforWebAssembly.cpp
> fi

Command 'clang++' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install clang
```

How is that possible? `clang++` is not supposed to be executed.

Comment: is `g++` installed? or rather in your PATH?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question you asked less than an hour ago ... [Why doesn't my script work on FreeBSD, even though it seems to work on Linux? It's as if FreeBSD ignores "if"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102945/why-doesnt-my-script-work-on-freebsd-even-though-it-seems-to-work-on-linux-it); granted, different command but the same issue ... script is not correctly determining if a binary is available and takes the wrong path through the `if/then` construct; did the answer (to the linked question) provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how **command** is used.

You need to **replace**

```
command -v g++ &> /dev/null
```

, in your code above, with

```
[ $(command -v g++ &> /dev/null ; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
```